PostgreSQL Snapshot Issues and Macro Customization Solutions
I'm facing a challenge with running a snapshot on our PostgreSQL database. The snapshot is too large to execute successfully, and I'm exploring alternative solutions. As an immediate workaround, I'm considering creating a customized macro to handle the situation.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with PostgreSQL snapshots? If so, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or resources that could guide me through this process. Are there specific strategies or articles you would recommend to efficiently manage large snapshots or optimize macro creation?
I have attempted to adjust the configuration settings to increase the maximum allowable snapshot size, but this hasn't resolved the issue. I've also looked into optimizing the database to reduce the size of the snapshot but with limited success. As an alternative approach, I am considering creating a customized macro to handle the situation more efficiently.
I expect to find a solution that allows me to successfully capture large snapshots without hitting size limitations or performance issues. Ideally, I would like to learn how to create a macro that can handle large data sets effectively or discover best practices for managing large snapshots in PostgreSQL.
